# How to Deal with Default Initializer when variable are not initialized Using Struct

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, swift, ios8

I'm using swift struct and trying to use its default initializer when my struct variables are not initialize, I try both non-optional and optional variables but in its only showing "memberwise Initializer".

below is example with optional variables

```
struct myFirstStruct {
    var value1:String?
    var value2:String?
}
```

below is example with non-optional variables

```
struct myFirstStruct {
    var value1:String
    var value2:String
}
```

and it only gives

```
myFirstStruct(value1: <#String?#>, value2: <#String?#>)
```

and i want to use `myFirstStruct()`

help me. :)

Comment: What is the initialiser you were expecting to be able to use?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Need to set default value.

```
struct myFirstStruct {
    var value1:String? = nil
    var value2:String? = nil
}

let object = myFirstStruct()
```

Comment: @ABakerSmith yes you said right, but his answer is giving both intializers :)

Comment: It's not necessary to write `= nil` though, you can omit them and it will still work.

Comment: This answer is correct but only deals with the case where all properties are optionals. See other answers for optional and non-optional properties cases.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode is only showing you the 'member-wise' initialiser, but it's perfectly valid to use `myFirstStruct()`, passing no arguments, because all your variables have default values.

```
struct myFirstStruct {
    var value1:String?
    var value2:String = "InitialString"
}

let s1 = myFirstStruct() 
// value1 = nil, value2 = "InitialString"

let s2 = myFirstStruct(value1: "Hello", value2: "World") 
// value1 = "Hello", value2 = "World"
```

Comment: Yes, I tested it in Playgrounds and in an app and they both run fine.